# Can a jQuery selector select all elements with an "onclick" attribute?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes, onclick

Basically, I just want to select every node that has the attribute `onclick` regardless of its value.

I tried this, but it does not work: `$('[onlick]')`

Comment: @BoltClock That would be an interesting event, though, if the browser could detect when the user licks a DOM element.

Comment: @Peter I'd have crashed my browser a long time ago due to lack of memory for storing events.

Comment: @JamWaffles I have a feeling I don't want to know what you do when you browse the internet

Comment: @Peter I browse lots of food websites `:)`

Comment: @JamWaffles I hope someone invents "taste-a-vision" and the onlick event so I can lick your name.

Comment: Yes.. $(window).on('lick',function(){sanitize();})

Comment: 7 years later and mankind is no closer to the dream of a lickable screen... 

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you add a `c` in the between the `n` and `l` in `onlick` it will work: `$('[onclick]')`

[You can see it working here.](http://jsfiddle.net/z9N9Z/)

Comment: Hahaha I feel stupid, but as far as "bugs" go... that's pretty entertaining.

Answer (score 1):

Try it in an Event Handler in IE9, wont work.

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j('[onclick]').addClass('turnedOff');
    $j('body').on('click', function(event) {
                           setTimeout(function(event) {
                   $j('[onclick]').removeClass('turnedOff');    
                }, 3000); 
    });
     });
```

The second $j('[onclick]') fails.
I had to create a function that removed the class.

This was part of an effort to turn off onclicks on a page covered up in Asyn Ajax calls.
a bad hack to fix bad design.
But it did show that the $j('[onclick]') will not work in event handlers in IE9
The

Comment: $j('[onclick]').addClass('turnedOff'); is $j('[onclick]').removeClass('turnedOff');  The class is added when a link is clicked.

Comment: But the important question: Does IE maintain the element's lickability? I don't want to remove the class if my divs wont be delicious anymore.